# Installing nginx via macports with ngx_echo module available

Tags: nginx

The [ngx_echo](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpEchoModule) module isn't included when I install nginx by:

```
sudo port install nginx
```

I looked at the portfile and the variants are:

```
addition dav debug flv geoip google_perftools gzip_static ipv6 mail perl5 realip redis secure_download ssl status substitution upload zip
```

Is ngx_echo included in any of those options?

Comment: I ended up using http://openresty.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled it using macports as mentioned in the link below

https://serverfault.com/questions/328416/how-to-set-random-value-in-the-specified-range-in-variable/347191#347191